# Assess and Address a failing hard drive - Is there a definitive guide, tool, or protocol?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, backup, time-machine, disk-utility

I'm running a Macbook Pro 2012 with the original internal hard drive. When I run "first aid" on it using Disk Utility, it reports that the drive is okay.

However, a SMART Status reporting app (in my case SMART Utility) indicates that my internal hard drive is failing as I have 2047 "Reallocated Bad Sectors".

I've seen some other answers referencing the different options for creating a backup or a clone, such as using:

1. The "Recover" tool in the built-in app Disk Utility
2. A third-party software tool such as Carbon Copy Cloner
3. A built in UNIX command such as dd
4. An open source tool such as dd-rescue or ddrescue
5. Something else, like the built-in app Time Machine

**Is there a preferred procedure or tool to safely backup a potentially failing hard drive?**
Or are there at the very least tools or procedures to avoid?

Or...are all of these options about the same in terms of their safety and ability to transfer from a failing drive onto a new storage device?

Comment: I'd try CCC as well as a normal Time Machine backup. The data on the bad sectors have been moved to an undamaged part of the disk ... for now. Get that disk backed up!

Comment: Is the benefit of CCC that it can be used to further update a bootable backup volume - meaning that it will only transfer and replace files that have had changes made to them since the previous backup created by CCC?